# Неправильное отображение сайта на планшете

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, media-queries

Делал сайт на заказ и заказчик присылает следущие фото сделаное на планшете Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.5 SM-T590 с 10 версией андроида:

[Картинка от заказчика](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gZ92.jpg)

Я начинаю тестить и у меня эта же страница на етих же размерах виглидт так:
[Мое изоброжение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JPRn.jpg)

Вопрос - что имено не так з воспроизвидением на девайсе заказчика, если на емуляторах и на ПК все нормально. Эсть предположение, что весь прикол в том, что размер шрифтов не тот, но почему он тогда на девайсе заказчика поменялся и как это исправить?

Comment: Вы используете `px` вместо `rem` в CSS? Если да, то это одна из причин. Потом viewport надо в мете html правильно указывать

Comment: иногда эмуляторы врут. Копай что не так в андроиде, какие версии браузеров у заказчика, какая плотность пикселей

Comment: viewport указа width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0. Так же на всем сайте используеться rem для размеров текста